# How do I set expiration headers for css.php?

Tags: php, css, performance, mod-expires, expires-header

I use Zend framework and I have lot of CSS file like this

> http://www.example.com/css.php?request=application%2Fthemes%2Flove%2Ftheme.css&c=2146&pageStart=15376&pageEnd=256358

How do I set expiration headers for css.php ? 
In fact my .htaccess don't work with it.

My .htacess :

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On
# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
# My favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year”
# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month”
# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following in .htaccess

```
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesmatch "\.(ico|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|swf)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, public"
  </filesmatch>
  <filesmatch "\.(html|htm)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, private, must-revalidate"
  </filesmatch>
  <filesmatch "\.(pdf)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public"
  </filesmatch>
  <filesmatch "\.(js)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, private"
  </filesmatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I use your .htaccess but nothing has changed

Comment: How you are checking something has changed after caching ? :)

Comment: Yes I have check with PageSpeed Insights by Google :)

Comment: @Rocstar are you facing issue only with css ?